# Can you parse a Date in the FB Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a string datetime in my Realtime Database. In the security rules I would like to check if this date is `> now`:

```
".write": "data.myStringDate.val() > now"
```

Since `now` is in milliseconds, I need to convert my string to milliseconds as well:

```
".write": "Date.parse(data.myStringDate.val()) > now"
```

But `Date.parse()` doesn't seem to work in Firebase: it returns `Unknown variable 'Date'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it isn't possible to reliably parse a string to a timestamp in Firebase Realtime Database security rules. If you need the value as a timestamp, consider (also) storing it as a timestamp.